# Display passed time in Flot time series

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, flot, series

I have managed to use time mode and display the absolute time, formatted from timestamps, on x-axis.

Now I would like to display the passed time since the first datapoint.

Example: first datapoint is 17:40 and second datapoint is 17:45, then the first point on the x-axis should display 00:00:00 and the second tick should display 00:05:00.

Is that possible with Flot?

Comment: As I understood you want to display a flat line for the time before 17:40...?  From what I know the only way is to fill the missing datapoints with null values for each tick between 0:00 - 17:40.

Comment: No. Sorry, maybe I did not express myself well.
I want to display the duration of my overall time.
Let's say I have 3 datapoints with timestamps for 17:40, 17:45 and 17:50
Then I want to display these labels on the x-axis:
00:00:00, 00:05:00, 00:10:00

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

The idea is to use 2 x-axes: the original one and second x-axis with time frame range starting from midnight and lasting for the same period as your original x-axis.

So for example first x-axis is `17:40 - 17:55` and second: `0:00 - ?` which we would need to calculate each time (now we know it will be `0:00 - 0:15` but flot needs a value in timestamp).

This can give you an idea how to calculate that:

```
1467906900000 - 1467906000000 = 900000 // difference between 17:55 - 17:40 (result: 15 minutes in timestamp)

1467842400000 + 900000 = 1467843300000 // 0:00 + 15 minutes (result: 0:15 in timestamp)
```

(if you find this timestamp thing confusing you can check out this [timestamp converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/))

Since now we have both ranges for our x-axes, we can add them to options:

```
"xaxes": [{
    "mode": "time",
    "timeformat": "%H:%M",
    "tickSize": [5, "minute"],
    "min": 1467906000000, // 17:40
    "max": 1467906900000, // 17:55
    "timezone": "browser"
  }, {
    "mode": "time",
    "timeformat": "%H:%M",
    "tickSize": [5, "minute"],
    "min": 1467842400000, // 0:00
    "max": 1467843300000, // 0:15
    "timezone": "browser"
  }]
```

The problem is that this second x-axis won't show up yet, if we don't assign any graph data to it. Luckily for us, we can easily trick it by passing an empty data set:

```
$.plot('.graphContainer', [
        {
        // data for first x-axis
            data:  [
                [1467906000000, 12], // data point at 17:40
                [1467906300000, 14], // data point at 17:45, etc...
                [1467906600000, 16],
                [1467906900000, 23]
            ],
            label: 'data1',
            xaxis: 1
        },
        // data for second a-axis (empty data set in order to force displaying second x-axis)
        {
            data:  [],
            xaxis: 2
        }
    ],
    options);
```

See my working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnjz1nyn/11/).